# Create a bitmap on touch

Tags: android

Hi i got the example which creates a bitmap on touch same is replaced and moved at new position when the user touches.Which works exactly fine but i have some other req which i want to use the same in some fragment of the some xml file..
But in the code he created his custom view and directly using that by setting to content view but i want the same action to appear in my layout.means i am not getting how to use that view in my layout please help me with code to use in my layout

public class SurfaceViewEx extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
 {

```
OurView v;
Bitmap cloud;
float x, y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    cloud = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cloud);
    v = new OurView(this); //Passing the context of this class
    v.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x = y = 0;
    setContentView(v);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    v.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    v.resume();
}

//It will handle drawing
public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Thread t = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder; //
    boolean isItOk = false;

    public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        //To make sure we can draw on canvas and surface is valid
        holder = getHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (isItOk == true) {
            //Perform canvas drawing
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                //Call back to while ..
                continue; 
            }
            //Lock the canvas, and unlock after drawing
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
            c.drawBitmap(cloud, x - (cloud.getWidth()/2), y - (cloud.getHeight()/2), null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
    }

    public void pause() {
        isItOk = false;
        while(true) {
            try {
                //Blocks the current thread until the receiver finishes 
                //the execution and dies
                t.join(); 

            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        //t = null;
    }

    public void resume() {
        isItOk = true; //Able to draw
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    switch(me.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x = me.getX();
            y = me.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //Same code
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //Same code
    }
    return true;
}
```

}